# Can I disable Google Software Update for a selected user account?

Tags: macos, user-account, google

From [this help file](https://support.google.com/installer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=147176) I know I can disable Google Software Update using:

```
$ defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0
```

Does this work for all accounts or just the current user account? I want to disable Google Software Update for the non-admin accounts that can't run it.

Comment: "When you update a setting using defaults, it only affects the current user."

http://commandlinemac.blogspot.com/2008/12/defaults-setting-preferences-from.html

It's poor form to ask a question and then answer it myself, but I couldn't find this question asked or answered anywhere. I'm fine if someone wants to delete it.

It looks like I can just run

$ defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0

on each of the non-admin accounts where the pop-up is so irritating.

Comment: It is actually typically a [*good* thing to ask, and then answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Instead of posting a comment, however, would you mind clicking the blue "Answer your question" under this? This way, you can accept it as an answer and future visitors will know what you found worked.

Comment: `defaults` can also be used to modify property lists that affect other users, but `defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0` modifies `~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Keystone.Agent.plist`, which only affects the current user.

Comment: thanks Laura and bassplayer. I actually had tried to answer my own question, but I don't have enough reputation points to do that immediately. I had to wait a day or two to have that privilege. I can do it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[repeating my comment as an answer to close the question]

When you update a setting using defaults, it generally only affects the current user." http://commandlinemac.blogspot.com/2008/12/defaults-setting-preferences-from.html

So I can just run

defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0

on each of the non-admin accounts where the pop-up is bothersome.